# sinon stub an array object

Tags: javascript, sinon

Having read the official documentation and searched, but I still have no idea about this.

Simple Source Code:

```
// obj is an object with an array element
// each element in array has its function
if (obj.arr['key1']) {
    return obj.arr['key1'].getValue();
}
```

What I want is controlling `obj.arr`, for example:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(obj, "arr");
stub['key2'].returns = {...} //add new Index 
delete stub['key1'].returns //remove old Index
```

Answer (score 2):

You can stub a function in an array like this:

```
myObj = {

    myArray: [
    function(){}, 
    function(){}, 
    function(){}
    ]
}

var stub = sinon.stub(myObj.myArray, [0]).returns() //insert what should be returned
```

Use:

```
describe ('foo', function () {

    it ('foo', sinon.test(function () {

        this.stub (myObj.myArray, [0]).returns();

    }))
}
```

if you want automatic cleanup after your stubs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Based on your answer, there is some misunderstand of my bad question (It's not your fault). But it still helps me to figure out the operation of the second parameter in `sinon.stub/spy/mock`.